# Trouble installing git Windows 10

Tags: git, installation, windows-10, 64-bit

Been trying to install the latest version of git (2.26.2) and I keep running into the same error message:

```
Line 2475: Unable to schedule the Git for Windows updater
(output: , errors: ERROR: Access is denied.
).
```

A similar version of this appears when trying to uninstall too:

```
Line 2486: Unable to remove the Git for Windows updater
(output: , errors: Error: Access is denied.
).
```

This also happens when I attempt to revert to a previous version of git (2.21.0). And even when giving admin privileges.

I have been using git for a while an not had any issues previously updating it. Despite this issue git still seems to install fine however is now refusing to store my github credentials so I am assuming it is due to this error in installation. How can I fix this?

I am using windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Have you ever deleted the **.git** folder and then downloaded **git** again?

Comment: Check the run status and authentication for a Service or Scheduled Task named Git for Windows updater.